# ¿Como usar la acción de JSF 2.2 en un botón de HTML5?

Tags: html5, jsf

¿Me pueden corregir qué es lo que hago mal? No consigo usar la funcionalidad de jsf sobre html5.

```
<form>
  <div class="mat-in">
      <input type="text" name="username" value="#{login.user}" required=""></input>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Username</label>
  </div>     
  <div class="mat-in">
      <input type="password" name="password" value="#{login.pwd}" required=""></input>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Password</label>
  </div>
    <button action="#{login.validateUsernamePassword()}">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para usar `JSF` necesitas su proprio lenguaje `html`.

Los tags cambian ( de `<input>` a `<h:input>` o `<p:input>`) dependiendo de la librería que estés utilizando (`Primefaces`, `Omnifaces`, etc...), y la extension del archivo también: creo que deberías utilizar `xhtml`.

Por cierto, ¿programas con `eclipse`?

Te aconsejo [Primefaces](http://primefaces.org/)

En su página te explican como instalarlo y además hay un montón de ejemplos a seguir en [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/)

Espero te sirva.
Un saludo,
Carlos

Comment: @Javier aquí tienes un enlace [http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/] con un ejemplo de hello world de jsf

Comment: Antes de añadir Primefaces, mejor que se familiarice con JSF "a solas".

Answer (score 0):

En JSF, se trabaja con Facelets para componer las vistas y lenguaje EL (expression language) para incluir las expresiones que permiten ejecutar un método de un Backing bean o realizar alguna otra acción.
En una fase final ese árbol de componentes generará el HTML final para el navegador.

Para ser un poco más productivo, te recomiendo primefaces y bootsfaces. Ambas te permiten crear interfaces potentes de manera rápida y con un HTML limpio además de atractivo con el uso de bootstrap.

Comment: ¿Y cómo sería la solución específica para el código publicado por el autor?